# How much safety margin in Vdss for an MOSFET 3-phase inverter working at V?

Tags: mosfet

When I design an H-bridge or a 3-phase inverter, I take my DC-Link voltage, say 48 V, and double it: ~100 V.

Then I chose a 100 V MOSFET for my application.

In my DC-Link I have 48V+-10%, then I could overshoot by 20% during breaking (motor driver).

What would be the rationale for choosing my Vdss?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on your question.  You're asking us what the rational for your choice of Vdss is?